# I want to run a 3rd party .exe file from a .bat file without a visible command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

Firstly I have created VBScript to run a batch file without a visible command prompt.

Following is the code:

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & ("D:\Intouch_Printer_SW\spool12\spltotext.bat") & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Following is my batch file code to run a third party .exe file.

```batch
for %%f in (C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\*.SPL) do (
    echo %%~nf
    start "" D:\Intouch_Printer_SW\spool12\spool.exe "C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\%%~nf.SPL" "Intouch Printer"
)
```

Whenever I run my .vbs code a console window pops up, I want to do all of it without a visible command prompt.

I think I am getting a black window due to this snippet:

```batch
start "" D:\Intouch_Printer_SW\spool12\spool.exe "C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\%%~nf.SPL" "Intouch Printer"
```

Comment: Have you tried call instead of start? Other than that you could use `start /Min` to have the command-line window minimized.

Comment: Thanks man! Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: Which of the both? I would like to add an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx) opens the command in a new window. It isn't required for running console applications, so you can simply remove it:

```batch
for %%f in (C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\*.SPL) do (
    echo %%~nf
    D:\Intouch_Printer_SW\spool12\spool.exe "C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\PRINTERS\%%~nf.SPL" "Intouch Printer"
)
```

In addition I would recommend running the batch script synchronously from the VBScript (3rd argument to the `Run` method set to `True`), to avoid undesired side effects should anyone ever modify the VBScript.

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """D:\Intouch_Printer_SW\spool12\spltotext.bat""", 0, True
```